# Calling the IAM API but getting error - "Method ListRoles not found for service iam.googleapis.com"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-iam

I am trying to call the IAM api using `curl`, specifically the `organizations.roles.list` method.

https://cloud.google.com/iam/reference/rest/v1/organizations.roles/list

From the docs, my request should be constructed like this:

`https://iam.googleapis.com/v1/organizations/<org-id>/roles`

However, calling it results in this error:

> {   "error": {
>       "code": 404,
>       "message": "Method ListRoles not found for service iam.googleapis.com",
>       "status": "NOT_FOUND"   } }

Full request: `curl -H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-access-token)" https://iam.googleapis.com/v1/organizations/<org-id>/roles`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm guessing this question is already outdated (almost 1 year), but I've copy-pasted your curl request, and it properly returned the custom roles in my org. If this is still failing for you, does the org ID appear when you try `curl -H"Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-access-token)" -H'content-type: application/json' https://cloudresourcemana
ger.googleapis.com/v1/organizations:search -d'{}'`?

Comment: I just checked [the release notes for the IAM API](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/release-notes#september_27_2017), and it appears that custom roles didn't go into beta until Sep '17. Since your question is from Jul '17, I'm assuming it's now working properly and the error was related to it being un-released at the time.

Answer (score 0):

[According to the docs](https://cloud.google.com/iam/reference/rest/v1/organizations.roles/list), the endpoint `https://iam.googleapis.com/v1/organizations/<ORG_ID>/roles` is used to list the roles defined at the organization level (i.e. custom roles).

To get the list of default roles (pre-defined roles, curated roles, whatever you want to call them...), you must call the API without specifying any resource:

```
curl -H"Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-access-token)" https://iam.googleapis.com/v1/roles
```

So, to get the complete list of roles in your resource (be it a project or an organization), you have to get the curated roles and aggregate them to the custom roles defined at the resource level, and the custom roles defined on the parent resources (so, to get the roles in a project, you get the curated ones+project custom roles+parent org custom roles).

As to the error you were receiving, I'm not receiving it now when testing it. I've run some tests and I'm receiving:

- 403 when I don't have the proper permissions
- 200 with empty response (`{}`) when there are no custom roles defined
- 200 with a list of roles [as defined in the docs](https://cloud.google.com/iam/reference/rest/v1/ListRolesResponse) when there are custom roles defined in the resource

Since the question is from Jul '17, and the custom roles [started their beta on Sep '17](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/release-notes#september_27_2017), I'm assuming you were too quick to test the API, and that's the reason for the 404 you were receiving.